# Integration of Stripe PaymentElement. Warning Unsupported prop change: options.clientSecret is not a mutable property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I have PaymentMethodPage, which looks like this:

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import {
  getClientSecret,
} from '../../api/PaymentCalls/PaymentCalls';
import PaymentMethodSetupForm from './PaymentMethodSetupForm/PaymentMethodSetupForm';
import AddPaymentMethodContainer from './AddPaymentMethodContainer/AddPaymentMethodContainer';
import {
  ClientSecretResponse,
} from '../../interfaces/paymentMethod.interface';


const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY as string
);

const PaymentMethodPage: FC = () => {
  const [enableAddPaymentMethod, setEnableAddPaymentMethod] =
    useState<boolean>(false);

  const {
    data: clientSecretKeyData,
  }: UseQueryResult<ClientSecretResponse, ExtendedError> = useQuery<
    ClientSecretResponse,
    ExtendedError
  >('getClientSecret', getClientSecret, {
    retry: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: enableAddPaymentMethod,
    onError: (error: ExtendedError) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
  });

  const options = {
    clientSecret: clientSecretKeyData?.client_secret,
  };

  const addPaymentMethodHandler = (): void => {
    setEnableAddPaymentMethod(!enableAddPaymentMethod);
  };

  
  return (
    <AppDrawer onLogOut={logoutHandler}>

          {paymentMethodData.default_payment_method !== null ? (
            <Box>
              <Typography>
                Payment Method
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          ) : (
            <Box>
              <AddPaymentMethodContainer
                addButtonHandler={addPaymentMethodHandler}
              />
            </Box>
            {clientSecretKeyData && (
              <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
                <PaymentMethodSetupForm
                  isOpenPaymentDialog={enableAddPaymentMethod}
                  handleClose={addPaymentMethodHandler}
                  setPaymentDialogOpen={addPaymentMethodHandler}
                />
              </Elements>
            )}
    </AppDrawer>
  );
};

export default PaymentMethodPage;
```

If there is no payment method I am rendering AddPaymentMethodContainer.
Which looks like this:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { Box, Typography, Button } from '@mui/material';

interface AddPaymentMethodContainerProps {
  addButtonHandler: () => void;
}

const AddPaymentMethodContainer: FC<AddPaymentMethodContainerProps> = ({
  addButtonHandler,
}) => {
  return (
    <Box >
      <Box >
        <img
          src={someImage}
          alt="no-payment-method"
        />
      </Box>
      <Typography>
        No payment method found. Click the button below to provide one.
      </Typography>
      <Box sx={styles.addButtonContainer}>
        <Button
          sx={styles.addButton}
          variant="contained"
          onClick={addButtonHandler}
        >
          Add Payment
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default AddPaymentMethodContainer;
```

Once the add button is clicked I am rendering the payment form, which contains Stipe PaymentElement...
The component looks like this:

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import {
  PaymentElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { useMutation, UseMutationResult, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent } from '@mui/material';

interface PaymentMethodSetupFormProps {
  isOpenPaymentDialog: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  setPaymentDialogOpen: (e: boolean) => void;
}

const PaymentMethodSetupForm: FC<PaymentMethodSetupFormProps> = ({
  isOpenPaymentDialog,
  setPaymentDialogOpen,
  handleClose,
}) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);


  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-return
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);

    const result = await stripe.confirmSetup({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/payment-status/',
      },
      redirect: 'if_required',
    });

    if (result.error) {
      console.log(`${result.error.message}`)
    } else {
      console.log('All okay!')
      setPaymentDialogOpen(false);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={isOpenPaymentDialog}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <DialogTitle>
        Payment Methods:
      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <PaymentElement />
          <CustomSubmitButton
            cypressId="credit-card-submit-button"
            isLoading={isLoading}
            text="Save"
            style={{ margin: '2rem auto', fontWeight: 'bolder' }}
            disabled={isLoading}
          />
        </form>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default PaymentMethodSetupForm;
```

Here I am disabling the function return type of handleSubmit, because I don't know what should be the type... It is a Promise<>, so If anyone has any idea(please help).
In general, all is working fine, what I do not like is when I click "ADD" button to open the form and I close it, on the second attempt when the button is pressed, there is a warning in the console:

```
Unsupported prop change: options.clientSecret is not a mutable property.
```

As well there is a warning regarding the images inside the PaymentElement ( for the card number ) :

```
Each dictionary in the list "icons" should contain a non-empty UTF8 string field "type".
```

And the last thing, which is very annoying. As per their documentation, I can disable the submit/save/pay button in the form like this:

```
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement />
      <button disabled={!stripe}>Submit</button>
      {/* Show error message to your customers */}
      {errorMessage && <div>{errorMessage}</div>}
    </form>
  )
```

But it looks like this object is always truty. I tried to make it like this:

```
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     {!stripe && (
      <PaymentElement />
      <button>Submit</button>
      {/* Show error message to your customers */}
      {errorMessage && <div>{errorMessage}</div>}
      )}
    </form>
  )
```

Because why should I disable it when I could just render it when the stripe is available.
But looks like it is not working like that. The submit button is always there, and suddenly the payment form appears... Which is not so nice. As a user, I got a button and at some time the form shows up. Okay, it does not take so much time, but in my opinion, it is not cool.

Answer (score 10):

**Add `key={clientSecret}` to the `<Elements>` component.**
Also can use [Update a PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update) or [Confirm a PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm)

---

Here is what Stripe team says about this:

> We don't currently support updating the clientSecret prop, and any attempted update will be ignored. This is the warning that is logged to the console when a clientSecret update is attempted:

```
Unsupported prop change: options.clientSecret is not a mutable property.
```

> We do have some in-flight work to address your exact use case though (updating the amount on the PaymentIntent after creation). In the meantime, a possible workaround is to remount the  provider and corresponding  altogether when the client secret changes by updating the key for the  provider:

```
-<Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
+<Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise} key={clientSecret}>
```

https://githubhot.com/repo/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/246

Comment: Stripe's own documentation logs out this error to the console if you follow step by step. The payment element redirects on completion, causing a state reset, thus logging the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `useQuery` but it looks like `clientSecretKeyData` is a changing value, and therefore `options.client_secret` is changing. As the error says:

> options.clientSecret is not a mutable property

You need to defer mounting the `<Elements />` component until the `client_secret` is available.